# Is the value for the Boltzmann Constant different in 2D?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, kinetic-theory-of-gases, ideal-gas

So I'm simulating some hard sphere collisions and want to determine the Boltzmann constant in two dimension, using the equation
$$PA=Nk_BT$$
where $A=\pi R^2_{container}$, $P=(averageImpulse/time)/(2\pi R_{container})$. $E_k=k_BT$(deg of freedom=2).
I'm plotting several graphs of $P$ against $T$ so that $$k_{B,2D}=\frac{A\cdot Gradient}{N}$$
but cannot get a consistent (constant) value for $k_{B,2D}$? In the sense that $k_{B,2D}$ keeps decreasing as I keep decreasing the radius of the molecules? Does this imply that no such a constant exists?

The spheres are too small to obey the VdW equation (at least 1000 times smaller than container)

Comment: Isn't everithing dimensionally incorrect at start? At the moment I don't see how this comment relates to your question but it seems an issue.

Comment: Why would you expect the Boltzmann constant to be dependent on dimension in the first place? Secondly, Boltzmann's constant is one of the seven constants of nature on which the SI units are based, it seems unlikely you can derive it with a simulation...

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1273.pdf may be of interest

Comment: @Paul assuming the first equation holds (the arxiv link I give suggests it does under appropriate conditions) and provided everything is measured in a consistent set of units I don't see why a value for $k$ can't be obtained. Who knows what units, but it should be a constant. However there is a lot of devil in the detail - is the velocity distribution properly equilibrated? Are there finite size effects that need to be accounted for? (Not sure) Are the stats for averageImpulse/time any good? And probably a whole load of other things.

Comment: @Ian_Bush, the LHS of the equation by the OP is in Newton and the RHS in Joules, so something is wrong. Obviously, the equation is a modified form of the ideal gas law and indeed a simulation of pressure times volume should give you a constant (i.e. the energy of the system), however this is not the same as determining the Boltzmann constant. In fact, you can only define temperature when using the Boltzmann constant.

Comment: It's not determining the Boltzmann constant. It's the equivalent of the Boltzmann constant in 2d which is being evaluated, and this will clearly have a different value and different units from the one we know and love

Comment: This is a weird statement, what do you mean by 'equivalent of the Boltzmann constant in 2d'? In essence, the Boltzmann constant is a conversion factor from energy to temperature and vice versa. From the equipartition theorem you can basically see that there is no dimensional dependence of the Boltzmann constant (each degree of freedom contributes $kT/2$ to the energy).

Comment: @Paul that is the point. k should hould be impose along each degree of freedom. At best one can look for a kind of Maxwell Boltzmann  distribution (I thin is what OP is dealing with) for a 2 D case.

Comment: I think this pdf can be useful to OP. K is taken independent of the number of dimensions, as in some of the comments above. http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/864.11/people/dhaval_adjodah/final_project/write_up_boltzmann.pdf